# How to add support of bcrypt to mysql?

Tags: mysql, debian, bcrypt

Following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20296312/1503018) mysql does not support bcrypt because system does not support them either.

How to add support of bcrypt to Debian to MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest `apt-get install bcrypt`

Answer (score 1):

You can install `bcrypt` from the **Unstable** Debian repository.

http://packages.debian.org/unstable/bcrypt

Comment: I have installed bcrypt from *sid* but mysql still does not suppoert bcrypt.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a User Defined Function (UDF) that can be compiled and loaded for MySQL or MariaDB:

https://github.com/ryancdotorg/mariadb-bcrypt-udf